# Does cotton really require all those harmful pesticides?

Tags: pest-management, farming

They say "cotton is bad because they use pesticides". But are they really necessary? Suppose your options are limited when it comes to dramatically reducing cotton farming's water consumption (because cotton naturally guzzles a lot of water). But can you make cotton sustainable with regard to pesticide application? Is cotton bad or those who conned the farmers into buying and using them or buying and using certain varieties of cotton that require so many pesticides, e.g. from Monsanto?

I've read some of a [paper](https://waterfootprint.org/media/downloads/Report68-WaterFootprintReduction-Cotton-India.pdf) on the topic of ways to reduce the environmental footprint of cotton cultivation in India, and it says some basic stuff: use more manure, mulch soils, rotate crops, etc. Why are Indian and other farmers so hooked up on unsustainable practices?

Comment: There is dry-land farming of cotton: https://agfax.com/2018/07/16/texas-cotton-dryland-crops-suffering-irrigated-fields-look-good/ . Also there is dry-land farming of sorghum.

Comment: Why are consumers so hooked on externalizing much of the costs of the products they purchase?

Comment: Because pesticides in the end lead to a larger/better harvest, thus earning more money.